# Angular: How to allow selecting values outside of ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

The [angular docs for ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) demonstrates the behavior of an attempt to set the ng-model value to a value that is outside the list - it instead set the value of ngModel to null.

How to allow selecting values outside of ngOptions?

Use-case: The large amount of valid options for ng-model can not be held in memory. In these cases, the options supplied in the UI are but some popular choices / results of a user free-text search. Initial values and user selections outside the current ngOptions should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

From the description it sounds like user will be searching a predefined data collection either from server or already in storage.

In that case you could use the selection event to capture the object selected and push it into the `ng-options` array, then set that new item as the model value